# why causes invalid format '%d in R?

Tags: r

The code given below is to convert binary files from float32 to 16b with scale factor of 10. I am getting error of invalidation of %d.

```
setwd("C:\\2001")
for (b in paste("data", 1:365, ".flt", sep="")) {
   conne <- file(b, "rb")
   file1<- readBin(conne, double(), size=4,  n=360*720, signed=TRUE)
   file1[file1 != -9999] <- file1[file1 != -9999]*10
   close(conne)
   fileName <- sprintf("C:\\New folder (11)\\NewFile%d.bin", b)
   writeBin(as.integer(file1), fileName, size = 2) 
}
```

Result:

```
Error in sprintf("C:\\New folder (11)\\NewFile%d.bin",  : 
invalid format '%d'; use format %s for character objects
```

I used  `%s` as suggested by R.But the files from  1:365 were totally empty

Comment: %d is invalid because (as R suggested) you are giving it a character vector (e.g. "data1.flt") rather than an integer.  You could use `for (i in 1:365) { b <- paste0("data",i,".flt"); ... sprintf("...%d...",i) }` instead, but this is unlikely to solve your real problem, which is currently unreproducible ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%d` is a placeholder for a integer variable inside a string. Therefore, when you use `sprintf(%d, var)`, `var` must be an integer.

In your case, the variable `b` is a string (or a character object). So, you use the placeholder for string variables, which is `%s`.

Now, if your files are empty, there must be something wrong elsewhere in your code. You should ask another question more specific to it.