# sprintf invalid format '%d'

Tags: c, r, printf, coercion

This works:

```
> sprintf('%d', c(1, 1.5))
[1] "1" "1"
```

and this doesn't:

```
> sprintf('%d', c(1.5, 1))
Error in sprintf("%d", c(1.5, 1)) : 
  invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Why?

Comment: I know I could use something like `sprintf('%.f', c(1.5, 1))` but I want to understand what is happening with the `%d`

Comment: I'm meditating over [sprintf.c](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/sprintf.c), so far it's hard to say exactly why the behaviour is asymmetric. There's a comment about coercion attempt at `ns = 0`, though the code around it is cryptic.

Comment: @RichardScriven what is in the help file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786169/why-causes-invalid-format-d-in-r

Comment: @PascalvKooten That doesn't answer why the first case works. Read my first comment

Comment: I see the same error when the integer is very large. i.e Even though 3e9 is an integer. I get the error when `sprintf("Number of Iterations:\t %d",3e9)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually really interesting question. To start, `%d` stands for integer. The vector argument is recycled if possible but if it is `c(1.5, 1)` it will fail when `sprintf()` tries to replace `%d` with 1.5 (which is not integer).

I thought it might be related to the fact that in R both integer and double are numeric mode, for example:

```
storage.mode(c(1.5, 1))
# [1] "double"
storage.mode(c(1, 1.5))
# [1] "double"
mode(c(1,1.5))
# [1] "numeric"
mode(c(1.5,1))
# [1] "numeric"
```

Thus both vectors should be stored as double. More info about vector in [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Vector-objects) and in the documentation for [`? numeric`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html):

> The potential confusion is that R has used mode "numeric" to mean ‘double or integer’"

I might have found the lines in [the underlying C code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/sprintf.c) which explain what is going on:

```
if(TYPEOF(_this) == REALSXP) {
double r = REAL(_this)[0];
if((double)((int) r) == r)
_this = coerceVector(_this, INTSXP);
```

This code does the following: If the vector type is `REALSXP` (which means numeric) then convert first member of vector to `double r`. Then cast `r` as integer and then double and if bytes are still same convert whole vector as `INTSXP`. Importantly, this code only checks the first element of a vector; if that element can be coerced to integer, then the whole vector is coerced, otherwise the code gives an error.

To test this hypothesis one could compile R with a custom `sprintf()` where `double r = REAL(_this)[0];` is changed to `double r = REAL(_this)[1];` and test whether `c(1.5, 1)` works now or not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this explains the differences between `c(1.5, 1)` and `c(1, 1.5)`

Comment: Excact answer can be found probably from here:[rsource/sprintf.c](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/46102b91b35a7befa0cf6cc6abd0da09b86f1621/src/main/sprintf.c). If someone with more experience with C could find it?

Comment: Great answer, weird implementation. It must been done this way for performance reasons.