# Convert seconds to days: hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: r, datetime

I want to convert the seconds into hours minutes and seconds in **R**.

Example

```
86400seconds-1day

gmdate("d H:i:s",86400)
```

This is how I tried.

Comment: Is gmdate() an R function?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You may try

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(86400)
#[1] "1d 0H 0M 0S"

seconds_to_period(48000)
#[1] "13H 20M 0S"
```

If you need to `format`

```
td <- seconds_to_period(86400)
sprintf('%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', day(td), td@hour, minute(td), second(td))
#[1] "01 00:00:00"
```

If it spans for `>99` days,

```
td <- seconds_to_period(1e7)
sprintf('%03d %02d:%02d:%02d', day(td), td@hour, minute(td), second(td))
#[1] "115 17:46:40"
```

Comment: And if the number of seconds is not an integer, you could use `%03d %02d:%02d:%02g` to print out the decimal value of seconds. Alternatively, one needs to round it in order to avoid an error by `sprintf` as `%d` works for integers only. See e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107405/sprintf-invalid-format-d

Answer (score 20):

Using base R, the following should work:

```
dhms <- function(t){
    paste(t %/% (60*60*24) 
         ,paste(formatC(t %/% (60*60) %% 24, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
               ,formatC(t %/% 60 %% 60, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
               ,formatC(t %% 60, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
               ,sep = ":"
               )
         )
}

> dhms(86400)
[1] "1 00:00:00" 
> dhms(48000)
[1] "0 13:20:00"
> dhms(1e7)
[1] "115 17:46:40"
> dhms(c(86400, 48000, 1e7))
[1] "1 00:00:00"   "0 13:20:00"   "115 17:46:40"
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works using `seconds.to.hms` from `kimisc`, though not as elegant as @akrun's answer:

```
library(kimisc)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

HMS = seconds.to.hms(86400) 

HMS = seconds.to.hms(48000) 

HMS = seconds.to.hms(1e7) 

HMS %>%
  str_extract("^\\d+") %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  {paste(.%/%24, .%%24)} %>%
  str_replace(HMS, "^\\d+", .)
```

**Result:**

```
[1] "1 0:00:00"

[1] "0 13:20:00"

[1] "115 17:46:40"
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an own function not depending on the **lubridate** package anymore:

```
my_seconds_to_period = function(x) {
  days = round(x %/% (60 * 60 * 24))
  hours = round((x - days*60*60*24) %/% (60 * 60))
  minutes = round((x - days*60*60*24 - hours*60*60) %/% 60)
  seconds = round(x - days*60*60*24 - hours*60*60 - minutes*60)
  days_str = ifelse(days == 0, "", paste0(days, "d "))
  hours_str = ifelse((hours == 0 & days == 0), "", paste0(hours, "H "))
  minutes_str = ifelse((minutes == 0 & days == 0 & hours == 0), "", paste0(minutes, "M "))
  seconds_str = paste0(seconds, "S")
  final_str = paste0(days_str, hours_str, minutes_str, seconds_str)
  return(final_str)
}

my_seconds_to_period(100000)
[1] "1d 3H 46M 40S"
```

Feel free to use or adjust it.