# how to convert a numeric vector into a time vector

Tags: r

in can r I have a numeric vector like c(15, 270, 540, 30, 15, 1440) representing minutes - but how can I create a vector out of this displaying hours and minutes?

Thanks in advance
Jasmin

Comment: Try with `library(lubridate);seconds_to_period(v1*60)`  Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312292/convert-seconds-to-days-hoursminutesseconds)

Answer (score 1):

This uses no packages and gives hours and minutes as asked (as opposed to days, hours and minutes).

```
x <- c(15, 270, 540, 30, 15, 1440)

sprintf("%02d:%02d", x %/% 60, x %% 60)
## [1] "00:15" "04:30" "09:00" "00:30" "00:15" "24:00"
```