# ggplot2::scale_x_time: Formatting hms objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data with a time-duration in seconds on the x-axis using ggplot2. The data is the result of either a simulation or is computed on a monitored trace.

I'm using `scale_x_time` to get proper labels. However, as the data spans a significant time frame, I would like to include the number of days and weeks in the labels. Minimal example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
n = 100
d <- data.frame(
    t = seq(from=0, to=100*24*60*60, length.out=n),
    v = runif(n, min=10, max=20)
)
ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=t, y=v)) + scale_x_time()
```

[image: ggplot output]

Is there a way to achieve just that using the [`hms`](https://hms.tidyverse.org/) package and base R?
Optimally, I would like to just give a format string, e.g. `"%Ww %dd %H:%M:%S"`.

The `hms` package contains plenty of helper functions to extract information from `hms` objects and format the objects. These functions are not exported. I had hoped to extract the number of days, format the number of days and weeks myself and then construct a new `hms` object and use the shipped `format` function. But I don't want to re-implement all the `hms` package's logic in my own code.

- https://github.com/tidyverse/hms/blob/160630c7601b3494ed9f2690b8cccd443cf10e64/R/hms.R#L197-L206
- https://github.com/tidyverse/hms/blob/60e11f484d07d8cb1bbde000d8f062ca7074f0c0/R/arith.R

My workaround thus far has been to convert `hms` objects to [`lubridate`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) period objects. `lubridate` has plenty of functions to extract information from periods. But this seems way too complicated to me. Also, periods express "human" time spans which does not match the use-case.

```r
library(lubridate)

format_dhms <- function(x) {
    p <- as.period(x)

    return(
        format(p)
    )
}

format_wdhms <- function(x) {
    p <- as.period(x)

    w <- floor(day(p) / 7)

    return(
        paste(
            ifelse(w >= 1, paste(w, "w", sep=""), ""),
            ifelse(w >= 1, format(p - weeks(w)), format(p))
        )
    )
}

ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=t, y=v)) + scale_x_time(labels=format_wdhms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this question/answer as a starting point "[Convert seconds to days: hours:minutes:seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312292/convert-seconds-to-days-hoursminutesseconds)" and extending to add weeks:

```
library(ggplot2)
n = 100
d <- data.frame(
  t = seq(from=0, to=100*24*60*60, length.out=n),
  v = runif(n, min=10, max=20)
)

wdhms <- function(t){
  t<-as.numeric(t)
  paste(t %/% (60*60*24*7), formatC(t %/% (60*60*24) %% 7, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0") 
    ,paste(formatC(t %/% (60*60) %% 24, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
           ,formatC(t %/% 60 %% 60, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
           ,formatC(t %% 60, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
           ,sep = ":")
  )
}
ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=t, y=v)) + scale_x_time(labels=wdhms)
```

Comment: That works, formats nicely and uses only base R! But all the no of weeks / days / hours calculations have to be re-implemented. I'm leaving this question open for now in case somebody comes up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: `as.numeric()` leads to rounding issues. The nested paste could be replaced by `format(hms::as_hms(t %% 24))` (but yields a decimal point for many values).