# time converson in R answer format

Tags: r, output, datetime-conversion

so I am trying to write a function in R to ask the user for an input value of time in seconds from user and then convert it back to hours minutes and seconds. here is my function for this below:

```
startT <- function(x) {
    t <-(readline(prompt = "Please provide the inital time in seconds: "))
    t <- as.numeric(t)
    return (t)
}

time_conversion <- function(t) {
    h = t%/%3600
    m = (t%%3600)%/%60
    s = (t%%3600)%%60
    final <- c(h, m, s)
    return (final)
}
```

Then using the following I can get the function to print my results as a list and then restore it as global variable:

```
initialT<- startT(t)
print(time_conversion(initialT))
TimeF <-time_conversion(initialT)
```

However, I was hoping (like I could in python) to print my out put as:

```
xx seconds, xx minutes, and xx seconds
```

in my python version I used:

```
return "%i hours, %i minutes, and %i seconds." %(hour, minutes, seconds)
```

I know based on my output from R I dont need to control for the output as variables. But can someone help me get this? We just started R so while I am sure there are more advanced stuff but I can't use that.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you can use

```
sprintf("%i hours, %i minutes, and %i seconds.", TimeF[1], TimeF[2], TimeF[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer:

[Convert seconds to days: hours:minutes:seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312292/convert-seconds-to-days-hoursminutesseconds)

It uses the lubridate package and even has a formatting example using sprintf().

-Emanuel