# My function for converting numeric seconds to HH:MM:SS is not working

Tags: r

I wrote function below to convert numeric value for seconds to format

HH:MM:SS

```
    my_to_time <- function(sec_vec_num,hours = T){
      sec_vec = seconds_to_period(sec_vec_num)
      if(hours == T){
        sec_vec = sprintf('%01g:%02g:%02g', sec_vec@hour, minute(sec_vec), second(sec_vec))
      }else{
        sec_vec = sprintf('%01g:%02g', minute(sec_vec), second(sec_vec))
      }
      return(sec_vec)

}
```

When I try to run this, I get following error though

```
 Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

The vector I am converting is numeric class. Not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: Post 5 values from `the sec_vec_num` vector

Comment: See this useful post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312292/convert-seconds-to-days-hoursminutesseconds/27313681 using ``lubridate::seconds_to_period``

Comment: I tested your code on the `numeric` vector `x <- c(1, 61, 3661, 86399, 86400, 86401)`, and once I had qualified the **`lubridate`** functions with `lubridate::`, my call to `my_to_time(x)` **actually worked**: `"0:00:01"  "0:01:01"  "1:01:01"  "23:59:59" "0:00:00"  "0:00:01"`. Are you *sure* your input vector is truly `numeric`?

Comment: Found my issue, another package was causing some problem, reload R and loaded only lubridate and the problem was solved. Thanks !

Comment: @GregorySmith Did that other package have a `minute()` or `second()` function (or even a `seconds_to_period()` function)?  If so, a way to avoid this in the future is to **fully qualify** all your **`lubridate`** functions like so: `lubridate::seconds_to_period()`, `lubridate::minute()`, `lubridate::second()`.  That way, a function like `lubridate::minute()` will never get masked by a `minute()` function from another package, which might work differently from what you expect.