# sprintf %d invalid format depending on order

Tags: r, printf, na

This is very similar to this question: [sprintf invalid format '%d'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107405/sprintf-invalid-format-d), but it is different. `sprintf()` gives an error formatting to `"%d"` for `c(NA_integer_, 1)`, but not `c(1, NA_integer)`.

```
sprintf("%d", NA)
#> [1] "NA"
sprintf("%d", 1)
#> [1] "1"
sprintf("%d", NA_integer_)
#> [1] "NA"
sprintf("%d", c(1, NA_integer_))
#> [1] "1"  "NA"
sprintf("%d", c(NA_integer_, 1))
#> Error in sprintf("%d", c(NA_integer_, 1)) : 
#>   invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Where it differs from the question above is that `sprintf("%d", NA_integer_)` works fine. Also, `NA_integer_` is explicitly an integer, so surely that can't be the problem?

Comment: When you combine that it is going to `numeric`, try `sprintf("%d", c(NA_integer_, 1L))`

Comment: Oh interesting. But why do you then not have the problem with `sprintf("%d", c(1L, 1))`?

Comment: It may be because of the type conversion to a single one i.e. `class(c(1L, 1))#
[1] "numeric"`.  In the former case, you are specifically asking `NA_integer_` and coerce with `1` i.e. `class(c(NA_integer_, 1))#
[1] "numeric"` and there could be some clashes